# Preferred features of CDN with DDoS?

Tags: tools, risk-management

I am putting together a presentation comparing CDN services that also provide DDoS protection. I have to do a really good job on this and I'm not a security expert. For lack of direction, I've copied most of these from a comparison article and could use a little feedback. I don't want a recommendation for a specific service, just to know what features I should have in the presentation based on best practices and your real life experience.

Here are the features I look at to compare among the services:

- Acceleration (network resources, content optimization, connection optimization, caching capabilities)
- Web Application Security (WAF, PCI compliant, custom security rules, two factor authentication)
- DDoS (Layer 3-4, Layer 7)
- Availability (local failover & balancing, global failover & balancing)
- Price (ADC package, potential extra charges)

**Are there any features you would add in addition to this?**

The site operates on a heavily customized Joomla core and will be used for distribution of e-content (mostly images, mostly ~500KB). At launch we do not plan to use it for any kind of direct sales, but we may have a premium subscription down the road (hence PCI compliant).